# odd url, and difficulty in following the php page flow

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to understand code that I bought so I can modify it.

In the index.php there are picture links:

```
<a href="test10,10"><img title="" border=1 
src="makethumb.php?pic=product_images/test101.jpg&amp;w=121&amp;sq=N" / ></a>
```

I don't understand the href since it is not pointing to a page. test10 is an id of a picture. I assumed it was going back to the index.php and the code would extract the test10,10 from the url, but it's not. I know that because I put in trace code as the first line.

The question is, where is the link going to?

I know it that it somewhere in the process it executes a page called profile.php, but nowhere in the source code (doing a global search) is there an explicit call to profile.php.

As a related question, is there a way to profile the code to see what pages it's calling without using xdebug, which for the life of me I can't get working after many hours of trying every suggestion I found here and else where. (I'm using xampp)

The flow is: you enter the site www.site.com/final/index.php. which displays pictures with the link as above. When you click on the picture with an id of test10 it takes you to www.site.com/final/test10,1

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is, where is the link going to?

Under normal circumstances, a request to

```
www.yourdomain.com/current_directory/test10,10
```

is made.

Usually, Apache will try to find a file of that name, and fail.

If the behaviour you get is different, then there is probably a `mod_rewrite` rule set up somewhere. Look for `.htaccess` files (note, files in parent directories affect all children) and check the `httpd.conf`, `httpd-vhosts.conf` and other log files for any `RewriteRule` settings.

Comment: thanks.
On my test apache, that no one touches except me, I wrote a test program linking to localhost/page.php/abc and it goes to page.php without a problem. the abc is visible in 4 places within $_SERVER

Comment: @sdfor can you post a full example URL of `test10,10`? Because if it's something like `domain/profile.php/test10,10` it will be routed to `profile.php` and `test10,10` will be in the `REQUEST_URI` / `PATH_INFO` variables. When you have a long chain of directories and one of them is an existing file, that file is called. Is that what's the issue here?

Comment: the code is exacty: 
    <td style=" vertical-align:top; height:190px"><a href="test11,11"><img title="" border=1 src="makethumb.php?pic=product_images/test111.jpg&amp;w=121&amp;sq=N" /></a></td>

Comment: @sdfor no, what happens if you click the link? What directory are you in?

Comment: ah,

www.site.com/final/index.php contains the link and we end up in www.site.com/final/test10,10

I became aware of the problem when I moved the site to www.site.com and got rid of the '/final' and now it starts in www.site.com/index.php and it tries to go to www.site.com/final/test10,10 which causes an error.

Comment: However, it doesn't go straight to www.site.com/final/test10,10. I know it goes to other pages in-between. Based on what you said I searched for mod_rewite function calls and I found a few, but that's not it, I commented them all out for a test. Is there some other function like mod_rewrite?

Comment: That's the problem, I can't figure out where it's going and how it gets to /final/test10,10. I wish I could get a profile trace working.

Comment: @sdfor I don't think a PHP trace will help you here, this is at Apache level if I understand it correctly. Still, your description is hazy. Can you rephrase, step by step (maybe starting when you enter the site), what exactly happens and from which point on `final` enters the equation? Best edit your question, that's probably too much for the comments.

Comment: "When you click on the picture with an id of test10 it takes you to www.site.com/final/test10,1" What is the exact full URL of that link? What is the content when you right-click the link and choose "copy URL" (or whatever it's named)?

Comment: The flow is: you enter the site www.site.com/final/index.php. which displays pictures with the link as above. When you click on the picture with an id of test10 it takes you to www.site.com/final/test10,1

I'm sure it's taking a circuitous route to get there. The question is how do I follow alink like href="test10,1" particularly when it's not going back to the page it resides on.
baffled.

Comment: @sdfor check my last comment before yours, I'd like to see the full URL (including server name.)

Comment: good point.
in firefox right mouse and "copy link location" results in www.site.com/final/test10,1

in the site without the final, a rightmouse yields: www.site.com/test10,1

Comment: @sdfor Okay. So there is no file with that name or `test10` in the root directory, right? There is no `.htaccess` file either? I'm off now but will check back later.

Comment: you're on the right track! great! there  is no page test10, but I found the htaccess! with the following:

RewriteRule ^fdfsdf\.html$ /final/page.php?document=58
RewriteRule ^fdfsdf\.html$ /final/page.php?document=
RewriteRule ^fsdfsd,html$ /final/page.php?document=
RewriteRule ^fsdfsd,html$ /final/page.php?document=
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ final/page.php?document=73

I'm not sure how to read that, but I'll learn.

Comment: @sdfor make a backup of everything and just remove `/final`. Might already work.

Comment: @sdfor then for safety, search the whole project for other mentions of `final`. There may be other locations where this is hard-coded.

Comment: I searched within the ide and the database. the ide didn't consider the htaccess file even though it's in the same directory. Live and learn.

thanks ever so much!!!